# Specify ContentType for Part of a FormData multipart/form-data Request

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

I'm trying to submit a multi-part form request using `FormData` in Javascript as the API I'm using requires this technique to submit binary files along with some JSON data.

By using `append()` on stringified JSON as the first part, and using it with a file from an input element as the second part, I get a request that looks like this:

```
-----------------------------14955296951218979377392396859
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"body":{"messageSegments":[{"type":"Text","text":"This is a file post."}]},"feedElementType":"FeedItem","subjectId":"me","capabilities":{"content":{"description":"File attachment from Clienteling","title":"Some File"}}}
-----------------------------14955296951218979377392396859
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="feedElementFileUpload"; filename="39191-ki1RNjpg-EdDM.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
*** SNIP ***
```

This is all good except that the API is saying I'm missing a required parameter, `subjectId`. That's clearly in there, and the sample documentation shows that the first part of the request should have `Content-Type: application/json` in it. That's not being put in by FormData and I can't find anyway to specify it. Is there a way to do so or am I going to have to find a way to build this request body manually?